# Why Lua's builtin REPL cannot access previously delcared local vars?

Tags: lua, read-eval-print-loop

See the following example:

```
$ lua
Lua 5.4.4  Copyright (C) 1994-2022 Lua.org, PUC-Rio
> local a = 123
> print(a)
nil
```

This works as expected:

```
> local a = 123; print(a)
123
```

How should I understand the behavior compared to the [doc](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#3.5)?

> The scope of a local variable begins at the first statement after its declaration and lasts until the last non-void statement of the innermost block that includes the declaration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Lua REPL, each (multi)line is loaded as an independent chunk via [`luaL_loadbuffer`](https://github.com/lua/lua/blob/be908a7d4d8130264ad67c5789169769f824c5d1/lua.c#L524). The same system that makes `require("mod_a")` independent of `require("mod_b")`.

Therefore, the quoted sentence still applies because every time the REPL prints a `>` (compared to a `>>` which denotes a [multiline](https://github.com/lua/lua/blob/be908a7d4d8130264ad67c5789169769f824c5d1/lua.c#L539)) a new block starts, thereby passing the boundary of "the last non-void statement of the innermost block".

Answer (score 2):

Lua REPL treats each line of code as a separate chunk (as if it was a separate Lua file).
When a chunk execution is finished, all its local variables are lost.
So, only global variables are preserved between lines.
Lua REPL is just a REPL, it is not a debugger, where you would be able to watch and modify all variables while program is running.

To use local variables in a multi-line program in Lua REPL: start with `do`, enter multiple commands, and finally enter `end` to execute the program you entered.

```
$ lua
Lua 5.4.3  Copyright (C) 1994-2021 Lua.org, PUC-Rio
> do
>> local a = 123
>> print(a)
>> end
123
>
```

Comment: "Lua REPL treats each line of code as a separate chunk" -- is this in the doc somewhere?

Comment: `is this in the doc somewhere?` - No.